# Need to Get the Table Cell Width Appended to a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Why is the property offsetWidth Working with a specific cell but not working when put in a for loop? Here's my code:

I need to get my table cell's width into a JavaScript object so I can process it on my server.

Right not I'm only able to get the highest cell width from the table. I want to put these values in a JavaScript object so I can send the values to a server.

I tried this:

```
<body>
 <table id="myTable">
  <tr>
<td> Test Data </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
  </tr>
</table> 
  <script>
var Str_txt = '{"Numbers":[]}';
var parse_obj = JSON.parse(Str_txt);
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
for (let i = 0; i < myTable.rows.length; i++) {
var row = table.rows[i];
var data = table.rows[i].cells[0].offsetWidth;
parse_obj['Numbers'].push({[i] : data});
}
Str_txt = JSON.stringify(parse_obj);
console.log(Str_txt);
</script>
</body>
```

Please help me get these table cell width values into a JavaScript object.

All I get is {"Numbers":[{"0":182},{"1":182},{"2":182},{"3":182}]}

When I want {"Numbers":[{"0":A Number},{"1":Another Number},{"2": Different Number},{"3":Dfiferent Number}]}

Thanks in advance